# python unknown label type error in a np array

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I wanted to make a classification task by using scikit. The dataset that I am working on is the concrete dataset available at:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Concrete+Compressive+Strength

My code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
data=np.genfromtxt("Concrete_Data.csv",delimiter=",")
X=data[:,:-1]  
y=data[:,-1]
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y)
mlp=MLPClassifier(solver="adam",alpha=1e-5,activation='relu',max_iter=1000)
mlp.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

But when I run it I got the following message error:

```
Unknown label type: (array([41.05, 67.11,  9.87, 43.38, 11.98, 19.99, 13.46, 35.1 , 28.6 ,
       36.8 , 17.58, 31.65, 34.49, 31.9 , 18.  , 55.65, 40.66, 53.96,
```

I have tried converting X and y by using `astype(float)`, but when I use type() I can see that the arrays are of type `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`. I have also checked the dimensions of the arrays and still got that message. How can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `MLPClassifier` model which (as its name suggests) is designed for classification problem where you have fixed number of possible target values in the training data (for example identifying if an image contains a cat or a dog). But you are working with a regression problem, where the model needs to predict the `Concrete compressive strength` which is a quantitative variable.

You should try to use the [MLPRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html) model instead of `MLPClassifier`